# Flash CS5.5: Photo is rotated when capture a photo using CameraUI on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Please help, I already succeed in accessing and capturing a photo through camera of an iphone. But the problem is when I load it in by "loadFilePromise", a photo is rotated wrong direction.

```
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.media.MediaType;
import flash.media.MediaPromise;
import flash.events.MediaEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.media.CameraRoll;
import flash.display.StageOrientation;
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;

var currentOrientation:String = "";

var cam:CameraUI = new CameraUI();
cam.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, captured);
cam.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelled);

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, photoLoaded);
addChild(loader);

captureBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, pressed);

function pressed(e:MouseEvent){
    if(CameraUI.isSupported){
        cam.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
    }
}

function captured(e:MediaEvent){
    var mediaPromise:MediaPromise = e.data;
    if(mediaPromise != null)
    {
        output.text = "Photo captured.";
        loader.loadFilePromise(mediaPromise);
    }
}

function cancelled(e:Event):void {
    output.text = "Cancelled.";
}

stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING,orientationChanging);
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, orientationChanged);

function orientationChanging(e:StageOrientationEvent){
    currentOrientation = e.afterOrientation;
    trace(currentOrientation);
    switch(currentOrientation)
    {
        case StageOrientation.DEFAULT :
            currentOrientation = "DEFAULT";
            //set rotation value here
            stage.rotation = 0;
            break;

        case StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT :
            currentOrientation = "ROTATED_RIGHT";
            //set rotation value here
            stage.rotation = -90;
            break;

        case StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT :
            currentOrientation = "ROTATED_LEFT";
            //set rotation value here
            stage.rotation = 90;
            break;

        case StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN :
            currentOrientation = "UPSIDE_DOWN";
            //set rotation value here
            stage.rotation = 180;
            break;
    }
}

function orientationChanged(e:StageOrientationEvent){

}

function photoLoaded(e:Event){
    var img:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content as Bitmap;
    img.smoothing = true;
    img.width = 350
    img.scaleY = img.scaleX;

    /* TRY THIS TO FIX BUT IT DIDN'T WORK:
        switch(currentOrientation){

        case "rotatedLeft":
            img.rotation = 90;
        break;

        case "rotatedRight":
            img.rotation = 90;
        break;

        case "upsideDown":

        break;

    }*/

    /* THESE LINE ARE JUST USED TO SAVE PHOTO IN CAMERA ROLL:
        if(CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData)
    {
        cameraRoll.addBitmapData(img.bitmapData);
    }*/
}

function camRollSaved(e:Event){
    output.text = "Your photo is saved to a camera roll."
}
```

I already unchecked "Auto orientation" in publish settings, tried to correct StageOrientation but it still didn't work.

```
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING,orientationChanging);
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, orientationChanged);
```

It's only correct when I rotate an iphone to lanscape (with the camera's position at TOP-RIGHT), then take a picture.

Does anyone has the same problem or know how to solve it?

Thanks so much,

Comment: This is a known bug. Please go to https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4070057 and vote it up, maybe Adobe will get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me on Android:
http://blog.flexnroses.com/?p=95

I think there is a problem with the libraries for iOS, so it might not solve your problem, but maybe you can get the inspiration you need from this. Good luck!