# How to upload a picture/image from iPhone to App in ActionScript 3?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm building an App with actionscript 3.0 in my Flash builder. but I'm having trouble finding code to use to upload an image in my phone to the app? can you link me/or post to sample code to achieve this task?

Thanks!

~Myy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`CameraRoll`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html) class. It allows the user to select an image from the device's "camera roll"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code [Capture Photo using CameraUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595050/flash-cs5-5-photo-is-rotated-when-capture-a-photo-using-cameraui-on-iphone), but picture orientation won't work properly on phone devices.