# JPEG encoder super slow, how to Optimize it?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder, image-conversion

I'm building an App with actionscript 3.0 in my Flash builder. This is a followup question [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970353/how-to-rotate-image-from-cameraui-for-ios-in-actionscript-3-0).

I need to upload the bytearray to my server, but the function i use to convert the bitmapdata to a `ByteArray` is super slow, so slow it freezes up my mobile device. My code is as follows:

```
var jpgenc:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(50);
trace('encode');
//encode the bitmapdata object and keep the encoded ByteArray

    var imgByteArray:ByteArray = jpgenc.encode(bitmap);
temp2 = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("snapshot.jpg");
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    trace('fs');
    try{     
     //open file in write mode     
     fs.open(temp2,FileMode.WRITE);
          //write bytes from the byte array

     fs.writeBytes(imgByteArray);
          //close the file

     fs.close();
         }catch(e:Error){
```

Is there a different way to convert it to a `byteArray`? Is there a better way?

Comment: Regardless of the performance of the code, why are you not running the work in a background thread along with the upload? Unless you can limit the input image size you will always find users who select big images and will dislike a non responsive app.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz In AS3, multithreading is very new and not yet supported on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use blooddy library: http://www.blooddy.by . But i didn't test it on mobile devices. Comment if you will have success.

Answer (score 1):

Use BitmapData.encode(), it's faster by orders of magnitude on mobile http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#encode%28%29

Comment: BitmapData.encode() is such a huge improvement over JPEGEncoder, it's almost comical.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find a JPEG encoder that is capable of encoding asynchronously. That way the app can still be used while the image is being compressed. I haven't tried any of the libraries, but this one looks promising:

http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/alchemy-asynchronous-jpeg-encoding-2

It uses [Alchemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Alchemy), which should make it faster than the JPEGEncoder from as3corelib (which I guess is the one you're using at the moment.)

Comment: Alchemy is not recommended for mobile - an ANE would be ideal

Comment: Encoding asynchronously only moves the performance problem around. BitmapData.encode() is a far better way of speeding up the JPEG encoding.

Answer (score 0):

A native JPEG encoder is ideal, asynchronous would be good, but possibly still slow (just not blocking).  Another option:

```
var pixels:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels(bitmapData.rect);
pixels.compress();
```

I'm not sure of native performance, and performance definitely depends on what kind of images you have.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ilya was what did it for me.   I downloaded the library and there is an example of how to use it inside.  I have been working on getting the CameraUI in flashbuilder to take a picture, encode / compress it, then send it over via a web service to my server (the data was sent as a compressed byte array).   I did this:

by.blooddy.crypto.image.JPEGEncoder.encode( bmp, 30 );

Where bmp is my bitmap data.  The encode took under 3 seconds and was easily able to fit into my flow of control synchronously.  I tried async methods but they ultimately took a really long time and were difficult to track for things like when a user moved from cell service to wifi or from tower to tower while an upload was going on.

Comment here if you need more details.

Comment: Now I am finding that the blooddy library is SUPER fast on Android devices (less than 2 seconds for pictures taken at 8 Megapixels on teh highest resolution on the device).  HOWEVER - it does NOT work on iOS.   It causes my application to hang, and the iOS to kill the program.

Comment: Is that still the case? Have you been able to resolve for iOS?