# Is there a faster way to encode bitmap data into a PNG than PNGEncoder?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, png, jpeg

I'm using the native Flash PNGEncoder library to encode a byte array to PNG and it's taking about 300ms per image. Is there any thing I can do differently to speed it up or is there another library that is faster?

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/Q7MiWg9u  - line 65

**Note**: The JPG encoder is about 10x slower than the PNG encoder but if one exists that is faster I would look into using JPG instead of PNGs.

**Note**: I don't have a problem using a JavaScript encoder if I can transfer the bitmap data out of Flash to the library and have it return before the AS3 library finishes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jPeg encoder super slow, how to Optimize it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009938/jpeg-encoder-super-slow-how-to-optimize-it)

Comment: It's said there to use `BitmapData.encode()` instead, if you're striving for performance. Maybe these encoders are unoptimized, deprecated and left for compatibility. (I had to do this within 10.1 Flash player, so I had no access to `BitmapData.encode()` and had to suffer 4-5s wait for 2880x2048 bitmap to encode.)

Comment: Does your encoder have some speed options? The slow part of PNG encryption is searching the LZ buffer for matches. Usually encoders have a setting that limits the amount of searching.

Comment: @Vesper - I'll try that and run some tests. There are some encoding options which I'll also try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very nice article that might help you: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2143

There is a `fast` property of the `PNGEncoderOptions` which I guess is `false` by default. The article also shows benchmark comparison between different approaches.

There is also a follow-up which has more tests and techniques inside: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2152

So you can chose one of the listed there and test a few images to see how it works, but as you know - it pretty much depends no the image ;)

Hope that works!